# "Row Last Modified" Script Produces Wrong Month

Tags: google-apps-script

This code has been working well for me, but today (when I modified a cell) I noticed that the script is producing a date that is one month behind the actual date (i.e., today is 6/5/2013, but the script produced 5/5/2013). Can anyone see what might be causing this problem?

---

```
// * based on the script "insert last modified date" by blisterpeanuts@gmail.com *
// Update cell with the the last modified time of any (single) cell in that row, excluding row 1 and column 1 

function onEdit() {
  var d = new Date();

  // format date nicely
  var month_str = d.getMonth();
  var day_str = d.getUTCDate();
  var year_str = d.getYear().toString().substring(2);


  // create the formatted time and date strings

  var date_str = month_str + '/' + day_str + '/' + year_str;

  // create the message (change this to whatever wording you prefer)
  // note also that rather than all the above, you could just use d.toString() 
  // I didn't because I didn't want it printing the timezone.
  var s = date_str;  

  var active_range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange();

  if (active_range.getHeight() == 1 && active_range.getWidth() == 1 && active_range.getRow != 1 && active_range.getColumn() != 1) {
    var update_row = active_range.getRow().toString();
    var update_cell = "AF" + update_row;
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(update_cell).setValue(s);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this has ever worked correctly for you. The [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMonth) for Date.getMonth() says:

> The value returned by getMonth is an integer between 0 and 11. 0
>   corresponds to January, 1 to February, and so on.

You need to increment the month by one.

```
var month_str = d.getMonth() + 1;
```

(Also the variable name month_str is misleading, it isn't a string, getMonth() returns an integer)

Comment: Thanks Daniel, your fix worked perfectly! I didn't create this script (and wouldn't know how to if I wanted!), but I'm glad I'm able to continue using it!